# can't access property of stdClass in TWIG

Tags: php, symfony, object, twig, stdclass

I have googled around and it seems as though the creators of TWIG really insists that what I am doing here, which is to me a pure job for the VIEW, something that the template shouldn't take care of at all?!

I know I can't iterate over an object of stdClass without some custom TWIg filters, so I hacked that for now, but if I can't eve access properties dynamically this TWIG thing really isn't very useful at all.

```
    $fixedModuleNames = array('time', 'date', 'weather'); //since TWIG doesn't iterate over objects by default, this is my solution, don't feel like adding a bunch of twigfilters just for this.
    $fixedModules = json_decode($entity->getFixedModules());

    /*
    Here's what fixedModules look like (although here not JSON but array, before encoded to json, I like to create my JSONs this way in PHP)
    $fixedModules["time"] = array(
        'show'          => true,
        'left'          => 10,
        'top'           => 10,
        'width'         => 100,
        'height'        => 200,
        'fontColor'     => '#000000',
        'fontSize'      => 40,
        'fontFamily'    => 'Arial',
        'borderColor'   => '',
        'borderRounding'=> 0,
        'bgColor'       => ''
    );
    */
```

Here's what I am trying to do...

```
                {% for item in fixedModuleNames %}
                <TR>
                    <TD><input type="number" id="left_{{ item }}" value="{{ fixedModules[item].left }}" class="LayoutModuleEditField" /></TD>
```

So this line fails

```
{{ fixedModules[item].left }}
```

There must be a way around this since what I am doing is very routine?

Comment: For the record: if you pass `true` as the second parameter of `json_decode` you get an associative array instead of an `\stdClass` instance.

Comment: Nice! Then however I seem to loose the "name" of each section ("time" in the example above). Is there a way to preserve that?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, is this perhaps the preferred way of doing it?

```
{{ attribute(fixedModules, item).left }}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your attribute function works then use it.

Consider however fixedModules[item].left.  You are asking twig to figure out that item is a variable while left is a constant.  Difficult for any system to do to say the least.

I would use something like:

```
{% for moduleName, module in fixedModules %} {# Time, Date, Weather module #}
    {% for itemName,itemValue in module %} {# Process each attribute in the module #}
        ...
```

If you want to iterate over an object then just implement the array iterator interface.  Usually pretty simple.

Comment: I don't see how what I am trying to do is different from any associative array in PHP? $array["subName"]["property"]

Answer (score 0):

`item` is not the key, but an element of your array. So you can access your attributes this way:

```
{% for item in fixedModuleNames %}
  left = {{ item.left }}
{% enfor %}
```

If you really want to use the key instead, do something like:

```
{% for key, item in fixedModuleNames %}
  left = {{ fixedModuleNames[key].left }}
{% enfor %}
```

Hope this helps.